# Inner Product of Fourier Series with Orthonormal Set

Tags: fourier-series, inner-products, orthogonality, orthonormal

I am stuck on where to go next for this problem. I would also like to know if my steps so far are correct.

If $c_n$ are Fourier coefficients of $f$ and $f_n$ is an orthonormal set, show that the inner product $$\left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,f-\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n\right> = 0$$

This is what I have so far:

$$\left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,f-\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n\right> = \left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,f\right>+\left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,-\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n\right> =$$ $$\left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,f\right>-\left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n\right> = \left<\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nf_n,f\right>-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}c_nc_m\left<f_n,f_m\right>=\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_n\left<f,f_n\right>-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}c_nc_m(1)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}c_nc_n-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}c_nc_m.$$

Comment: As $\{f_n\}$ is an orthonormal set, $\langle f_n, f_m \rangle =.\delta_{n,m}$, not $1$ as you wrote. Hence,
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{m=1}^N c_n c_m \langle f_n, f_m \rangle
= \sum_{n=1}^N c_n^2$$

The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: I thought that $\delta_{nm} = 1$ when $n$ and $m$ are equal?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see now. $n$ would be fixed in that case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $f_k$ with $k \in \{1,...,N\}$, then
$\langle f_k , f-\sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n \rangle = \langle f_k , f \rangle - \langle f_k , \sum_{n=1}^N c_n f_n \rangle = \langle f_k , f \rangle - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n\langle f_k , f_n \rangle = c_k -c_k = 0$.

Comment: I do not see how the second inner product is equal to $c_k$. Could you expand it a bit more?

Comment: because the set is orthonormal, the inner product will be characteristic on the set. Hence, if $k \neq n$, the inner product will be zero by assumption. Expand the second inner product linearly and note that for each term, $\sum_{n=1}^{N} c_n \langle f_k, f_n \rangle$, which should tell you why the equality is true, since $\langle f_k,f_n\rangle =0$ for $k \neq n$.

Answer (score 0):

The last part is not quite right. It should be $\big \langle \sum_{n=1}^N c_nf_n,f \big \rangle - \sum_{n=1}^N \sum_{m=1}^N c_nc_m \langle f_n,f_m \rangle=  \sum_{n=1}^N c_n \langle f, f_n \rangle - \sum_{n=1}^N c_n^2$

Comment: That is what I showed my professor, but he said that it was incorrect.

Comment: Only the diagonal terms are nonzero because  $f_n$ is an orthonormal set.